# Do C# reference types allocates new memory when passed to methods?

Tags: c#, reference, memory-management

everyone... I'm new to C# and such languages...

I've read two articles by Skeet, one about [heap/stack](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html), and other about [reference types and value types](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html). And I assume my question is simple, but it's not clarified to me after reading those articles.

Do reference types allocate new memory when passed to methods?

For example, if I pass a Form to a method, like

```
void myMethod(System.Windows.Forms.Form myForm)
{
...
}
```

Will there be more memory allocated to store all `myForm` data or will it hold just a reference to where `myForm` data is already allocated?

My worry is that if there's more memory allocated to store everything "appended" to `myForm`, soon the memory could become full, if `myForm` were a big form...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you instantiate your original form, the form object will allocated on the heap. When you call myMethod, you're passing a reference type (essentially a pointer to that object) by value. That means that the reference you're passing in will be copied in the context of myMethod - this involves a 32/64 bit stack allocation, depending on your architecture.

So, to answer your question, your form will not be copied but the reference to it will be.

Disclaimer: I haven't used C# in ages.

Comment: Congrats, you have now 2013 reps, happy new year 2013 :)

Answer (score 2):

Technically they will create a copy of the reference (so another 'reference-sized' memory allocation), but the actual object referenced will not be copied and re-allocated.

Answer (score 2):

No. Passing a `Form` reference to a function is no more expensive than passing an integer.

A `Form` is a large object (probably tens of KB when you add everything up). Only a reference to it can be passed as a parameter. This reference is only 4 bytes (in a 32-bit process) and vanishes when the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

No, only a reference is allocated.

In C# an instance of a reference type can only be passed by reference. That is, the object itself is never copied, only the reference to it is.
<sup>Strictly speaking, when you pass an object to a method, its reference is passed *by value*. Which means, you can access the object using this reference, and changes you make to the object will be visible to the code that called your method, but, if you make that received reference point to some other object, that change will not affect the code that gave you the original reference -- because the reference was passed by value.</sup>

As opposed to value types that, when passed by value, do get copied.

Comment: No, you can pass both reference types and value types *by reference*.

Comment: Yes, but I'm only saying you cannot do the other way round.

Comment: Might be, but then your sentence "you can only pass [...] a reference type by reference" is highly confusing, because you can also pass value types by reference.

Comment: Reference types are passed by reference only in the same manner that value types are passed by reference: explicitly. Don't confuse that with passing the value of the address.

Comment: And *reference types* are not named that way because of the way how they are passed to methods, see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html. Please correct your answer.

Comment: @Anthony Pengram: Saying *Note that when you pass an object 'by reference' you actually pass a reference to it by value*, while technically correct, is highly irrelevant to this particular question. And if you are saying that in C# objects, unless explicitly stated, get passed by value, like they would in, say, C++, then you are wrong.

Comment: @GSerg: Sorry, it is still not correct. Reference types can be passed by value (the default) or by reference (using `ref` or `out`) as well as value types can be passed by value (the default) or by reference (using `ref` or `out`). Re-read Jon's article and things will get clearer. The topic is difficult and the differences are only sublte - but important.

Comment: @0xA3: Which brings us to the comment I left [at]Anthony Pengram. You are saying, the reference is passed by value, and I am saying, yes, it is, but that is irrelevant in terms of whether the object is copied or not (which it never is). Oh well. I will it include that, too.

Answer (score 1):

A Form is a class. In C# a class is a reference type - which means that when it passed around it is passed *by reference*. This basically means that the address of the memory where the Form instance resides is passed into the stack frame instead of copying all of the bytes.

If the method parameter was struct or a primitive type like an int, then it would be a value type. Value types, when passed into methods, have all of their data copied into the stack frame of the method.